# Exception 3 thrown during clear() or when destroying vectors

Tags: c++, vector, arduino, esp8266, arduino-esp8266

#### Description

Sometimes I get exception 3 when trying to clear() a std::vector.

#### Hardware

- Hardware: ESP-07S
- ESP8266-Arduino library core version: 2.4.0-rc1

#### Settings in IDE

- Module: Generic ESP8266 Module
- Flash Size: 4MB
- CPU Frequency:   160Mhz
- Flash Mode:  qio
- Flash Frequency: 40Mhz
- Upload Using:    OTA / SERIAL
- Reset Method:    ck

#### Stacktrace

This is stacktrace from Arduino's Exception Decoder:

```
Exception 3: LoadStoreError: Processor internal physical address or data error during load or store
Decoding 30 results
0x401000b7: umm_disconnect_from_free_list at C:\Users\Defozo\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\2.4.0-rc1\cores\esp8266\umm_malloc/umm_malloc.c line 1151
0x4021e9bc: memmove at /Users/igrokhotkov/e/newlib-xtensa/xtensa-lx106-elf/newlib/libc/string/../../../.././newlib/libc/string/memmove.c line 69 (discriminator 1)
0x40217464: Print::write(unsigned char const*, unsigned int) at C:\Users\Defozo\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\2.4.0-rc1\cores\esp8266/Print.cpp line 38
0x4010020c: _umm_free at C:\Users\Defozo\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\2.4.0-rc1\cores\esp8266\umm_malloc/umm_malloc.c line 1287
0x4010068c: free at C:\Users\Defozo\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\2.4.0-rc1\cores\esp8266\umm_malloc/umm_malloc.c line 1733
0x40215b04: operator delete(void*) at C:\Users\Defozo\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\2.4.0-rc1\cores\esp8266/abi.cpp line 57
0x40207940: std::_Vector_base   >::_M_deallocate(double*, unsigned int) at C:\Users\Defozo\Documents\Arduino\jeszcze nowsza wersja laser_na_stacje_v2\laser_na_stacje_v2/laser_na_stacje_v2.ino line 565
0x402088ac: std::_Vector_base   >::~_Vector_base() at c:\users\defozo\appdata\local\arduino15\packages\esp8266\tools\xtensa-lx106-elf-gcc\1.20.0-26-gb404fb9-2\xtensa-lx106-elf\include\c++\4.8.2\bits/stl_vector.h line 161
0x40209748: std::vector   >::_M_erase_at_end(double*) at c:\users\defozo\appdata\local\arduino15\packages\esp8266\tools\xtensa-lx106-elf-gcc\1.20.0-26-gb404fb9-2\xtensa-lx106-elf\include\c++\4.8.2\bits/stl_vector.h line 1353
:  (inlined by) std::vector   >::clear() at c:\users\defozo\appdata\local\arduino15\packages\esp8266\tools\xtensa-lx106-elf-gcc\1.20.0-26-gb404fb9-2\xtensa-lx106-elf\include\c++\4.8.2\bits/stl_vector.h line 1126
:  (inlined by) loop at C:\Users\Defozo\Documents\Arduino\jeszcze nowsza wersja laser_na_stacje_v2\laser_na_stacje_v2/laser_na_stacje_v2.ino line 412
0x40217082: std::default_delete ::operator()(TransportTraits*) const at c:\users\defozo\appdata\local\arduino15\packages\esp8266\tools\xtensa-lx106-elf-gcc\1.20.0-26-gb404fb9-2\xtensa-lx106-elf\include\c++\4.8.2\bits/unique_ptr.h line 68
0x4010020c: _umm_free at C:\Users\Defozo\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\2.4.0-rc1\cores\esp8266\umm_malloc/umm_malloc.c line 1287
0x401020ea: wDev_ProcessFiq at ?? line ?
0x40215d84: loop_wrapper at C:\Users\Defozo\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\2.4.0-rc1\cores\esp8266/core_esp8266_main.cpp line 124
0x4010070c: cont_norm at C:\Users\Defozo\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\2.4.0-rc1\cores\esp8266/cont.S line 109
```

This is reset cause:

```
Hardware Watchdog
Fatal exception:4 flag:1 (WDT) epc1:0x40000f83 epc2:0x00000000 epc3:0x4000dd3b excvaddr:0x40023c5c depc:0x00000000
```

#### Code

I'm initializing vectors like that:

```
std::vector<double> dhtTempVector, dhtHumidityVector;
std::vector<double> dhtTempMedianVector, dhtHumidityMedianVector;
std::vector<double> bmpTempVector, bmpPressureVector;
std::vector<double> bmpTempMedianVector, bmpPressureMedianVector;
dhtTempVector.reserve(5);
dhtHumidityVector.reserve(5);
bmpTempVector.reserve(5);
bmpPressureVector.reserve(5);
dhtTempMedianVector.reserve(6);
dhtHumidityMedianVector.reserve(6);
bmpPressureMedianVector.reserve(6);
bmpTempMedianVector.reserve(6);
```

Inserting new values like that:

```
if (!isnan(temp) && !isnan(hum)) {
    dhtTempVector.push_back(temp);
    dhtHumidityVector.push_back(hum);
}
```

and:

```
if (!dhtTempVector.empty()) {
    dhtTempMedianVector.push_back(median(dhtTempVector));
    dhtTempVector.clear();
}
if (!dhtHumidityVector.empty()) {
    dhtHumidityMedianVector.push_back(median(dhtHumidityVector));
    dhtHumidityVector.clear(); //line number 412
}
```

This is the median function:

```
double median(std::vector<double> v)
{
    size_t n = v.size() / 2;
    std::nth_element(v.begin(), v.begin()+n, v.end());
    double vn = v[n];
    if(v.size()%2 == 1) {
        return vn;
    } else  {
        std::nth_element(v.begin(), v.begin()+n-1, v.end());
        return 0.5*(vn+v[n-1]);
    }
}
```

#### Additional debug information

This is a result:

```
dhtTempVector size: 4
dhtTempMedianVector size: 5
dhtHumidityVector size: 4
dhtHumidityMedianVector size: 5
29.00 29.00 29.00 29.00 --
28.70 28.75 28.80 28.90 28.90 --
41.20 41.30 41.80 41.40 --
42.65 42.55 41.80 42.30 41.75 --
```

of these lines of code:

```
Serial.print("dhtTempVector size: ");
Serial.println(dhtTempVector.size());
Serial.print("dhtTempMedianVector size: ");
Serial.println(dhtTempMedianVector.size());
Serial.print("dhtHumidityVector size: ");
Serial.println(dhtHumidityVector.size());
Serial.print("dhtHumidityMedianVector size: ");
Serial.println(dhtHumidityMedianVector.size());
for (int k = 0; k < dhtTempVector.size(); ++k) {
    Serial.print(dhtTempVector.at(k));
    Serial.print(" ");
}
Serial.println("--");
for (int k = 0; k < dhtTempMedianVector.size(); ++k) {
    Serial.print(dhtTempMedianVector.at(k));
    Serial.print(" ");
}
Serial.println("--");
for (int k = 0; k < dhtHumidityVector.size(); ++k) {
    Serial.print(dhtHumidityVector.at(k));
    Serial.print(" ");
}
Serial.println("--");
for (int k = 0; k < dhtHumidityMedianVector.size(); ++k) {
    Serial.print(dhtHumidityMedianVector.at(k));
    Serial.print(" ");
}
Serial.println("--");
```

just before the exception is thrown.

#### Summary

It looks like the exception is thrown during clearing the vector. I think I experienced exceptions thrown at the end of the loop() function too - so at the time when destructors of the vectors are fired. I'd think it's a problem with destroying the elements of the vectors but they're just double numbers.

What could be the problem?

**@Edit**

The **Arduino-ESP8266 library** that I'm using is available here:
https://github.com/esp8266

Here is **umm_malloc.c**:
https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino/blob/master/cores/esp8266/umm_malloc/umm_malloc.c

**Print.cpp**:
https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino/blob/4897e0006b5b0123a2fa31f67b14a3fff65ce561/cores/esp8266/Print.cpp

**cont.S**:
https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino/blob/4897e0006b5b0123a2fa31f67b14a3fff65ce561/cores/esp8266/cont.S

Specific **lines from umm_malloc.c**:

1151:

```
UMM_NFREE(UMM_PFREE(c)) = UMM_NFREE(c);
```

https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino/blob/master/cores/esp8266/umm_malloc/umm_malloc.c#L1151

1287:

```
if( UMM_NBLOCK(UMM_PBLOCK(c)) & UMM_FREELIST_MASK ) {
```

https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino/blob/master/cores/esp8266/umm_malloc/umm_malloc.c#L1287

1733:

```
void umm_free( void *ptr ) {

  ptr = GET_UNPOISONED(ptr);

  /* check poison of each blocks, if poisoning is enabled */
  if (!CHECK_POISON_ALL_BLOCKS()) {
    return;
  }

  /* check full integrity of the heap, if this check is enabled */
  if (!INTEGRITY_CHECK()) {
    return;
  }

  _umm_free( ptr );
} //1733
```

https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino/blob/master/cores/esp8266/umm_malloc/umm_malloc.c#L1733

Specific **line from Print.cpp**:

```
size_t Print::write(const uint8_t *buffer, size_t size) {
    size_t n = 0;
    while(size--) {
        n += write(*buffer++); //line number 38
    }
    return n;
}
```

https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino/blob/4897e0006b5b0123a2fa31f67b14a3fff65ce561/cores/esp8266/Print.cpp#L38

Specific **line from core_esp8266_main.cpp**:

```
static void loop_wrapper() {
    static bool setup_done = false;
    preloop_update_frequency();
    if(!setup_done) {
        setup();
#ifdef DEBUG_ESP_PORT
        DEBUG_ESP_PORT.setDebugOutput(true);
#endif
        setup_done = true;
    }
    loop();
    run_scheduled_functions(); //line number 124
    esp_schedule();
}
```

Line number 109 from cont.S:

https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino/blob/4897e0006b5b0123a2fa31f67b14a3fff65ce561/cores/esp8266/cont.S#L109

Comment: all of this seems to happen in some private implementation of the package, except a few standard calls like 'memmove' . you need to look at the line numbers provided in the stack dump. Or at least provide them.

Comment: I added them to the question.

Comment: difficult to say without real playing with the program.  I have 3 possibilities in mind (1) On the top it looks like some kind of initialization order, i.e. it does clean() before constructing your vectors. Why does it 'clear' at all? (2) Another possibility is a memory corruption. I do not like the 1151 line. It looks like the malloc list is corrupted. (3) there is an extra 'free' for already freed memory which could probably also explain 1151.

Comment: This looks like a heap corruption error.  It could come from a write to this, or another array being out of bounds.

Comment: Is it possible to write something out of bounds of vector using only `push_back` method?

Comment: @Defozo have you managed to solve this problem?

Comment: Initially, I simply got rid of the vectors by replacing them with arrays. However, later on, I noticed that I might or might not exceed limit of PWM value in `analogWrite()` function. So, maybe that was the problem? Never checked again with vectors.